# Inter-Rater Reliabilty: Running multiple Cohen's Kappa simultaneously (using R)

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, correlation

I am trying to calculate cohen's kapa values for multiple teacher-segment permutations. In this exampe, there are six unique teacher-segment combinations. For example, teacher1-segement1 has two different raters, and would like to see the ICC of these two raters for that teacher1-segement1 (and all the other teacher-segment permuations).

I have a data set such as this.

```
full.data <- read_table2('Rater teacher segment subject1    subject2    subject3
A   1   1   1   4   1
B   1   1   3   4   3
B   2   2   2   3   2
C   2   2   1   4   1
D   3   1   4   4   4
E   3   1   4   3   4
D   4   2   3   3   3
A   4   2   4   3   4
B   5   2   4   3   4
A   5   2   5   3   5
D   6   1   5   3   5
E   6   1   5   3   5')
```

I know that if I wanted to get cohen's kapa for just one teacher-segment group, I would tranform the data such as this,

```
one.permuation<- read_table2('Rater RaterA-teacher1-segment1    RaterB-teacher1-segment1
subject1    1   3
subject2    4   4
subject3    1   3')

and then run,
library(irr)
print(icc(myRatings, model=“twoway”, type=“consistency”, unit=“average”))
```

Which would give me just ONE kapa value for that particular teacher-segment.

1. How would I get the values for all the teacher-segment permutations at once? (each group of teacher,segment, has a different observer)?
2. How do I present these 6 different Kapa values in a way that makes sense? I've never done something like this before; hoping to get some insight from experienced stat folks.
3. Although not shown here, raters have both an ordinal and nominal scale response (1-4 score) and [yes, No]. Should I be using a different kappa function for these different kinds of scales? From the "Psych" library documentation: "Cohen's kappa (Cohen, 1960) and weighted kappa (Cohen, 1968) may be used to find the agreement of two raters when using nominal scores."

Comment: What package is `icc()` from? Please make your code reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I tried for you. You said that you want to calculate Cohen's Kappa values. So I decided to use `cohen.kappa()` in the psych package, rather than `icc()`, which I am not familiar with. I hope you do not mind that. They key thing was to transform your data in a way that you can run `cohen.kappa()` all together. Seeing your `one.permuation`, I tried to create a data frame that has teacher, segment, subject, and raters (A, B, C, D, and E) as columns. `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` handled this. Then, I needed to move numeric values to two columns (rowwise value sorting). I used Ananda Mahto's `SOfun` package. (Ananda is the author of splitstackshape package.) Then, I grpup the data by teacher and segment and created lists. For each list that contains a data frame, I converted the data frame to matrix and applied `cohen.kappa()` and obtained results with `tidy()`. Finally, I used `unnest()` to see the results.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)
library(devtools)
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")
library(SOfun)
library(broom)

pivot_longer(full.data, cols = subject1:subject3,
             names_to = "subject", values_to = "rating_score") %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c("teacher", "segment", "subject"),
             names_from = "Rater", values_from = "rating_score") %>%
as.matrix %>% 
naLast(by = "row") %>% 
as_tibble %>% 
select(-c(subject, C:E)) %>% 
type_convert() %>% 
group_by(teacher, segment) %>%
nest() %>% 
mutate(result = map(.x = data,
                    .f = function(x) cohen.kappa(as.matrix(x)) %>% tidy())) %>% 
unnest(result)

#  teacher segment           data type       estimate conf.low conf.high
#     <dbl>   <dbl> <list<df[,2]>> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1       1       1        [3 x 2] unweighted    0.25   -0.0501     0.550
# 2       1       1        [3 x 2] weighted      0.571  -0.544      1    
# 3       2       2        [3 x 2] unweighted    0       0          0    
# 4       2       2        [3 x 2] weighted      0.571  -1          1    
# 5       3       1        [3 x 2] unweighted    0       0          0    
# 6       3       1        [3 x 2] weighted      0       0          0    
# 7       4       2        [3 x 2] unweighted    0       0          0    
# 8       4       2        [3 x 2] weighted      0       0          0    
# 9       5       2        [3 x 2] unweighted    0.25   -0.0501     0.550
#10       5       2        [3 x 2] weighted      0.571  -0.544      1    
#11       6       1        [3 x 2] unweighted    1       1          1    
#12       6       1        [3 x 2] weighted      1       1          1
```

**icc version**

The data transformation is basically the same. You need to work a bit more when you run multiple stats. `icc()` returns `icclist` object. You want to create data frames from the object.

```
library(irr)

pivot_longer(full.data, cols = subject1:subject3,
             names_to = "subject", values_to = "rating_score") %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c("teacher", "segment", "subject"),
            names_from = "Rater", values_from = "rating_score") %>%
as.matrix %>% 
naLast(by = "row") %>% 
as_tibble %>% 
select(-c(subject, C:E)) %>% 
mutate_at(vars(A:B), .funs = list(~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
group_by(teacher, segment) %>%
nest() %>% 
mutate(result = map(.x = data,
                    .f = function(x) enframe(unlist(icc(x, 
                                                        model = "twoway",
                                                        type = "consistency", 
                                                        unit = "average"))) %>% 
                                     pivot_wider(names_from = "name",
                                                 values_from = "value"))) %>% 
unnest(result)


 teacher segment     data subjects raters model type  unit  icc.name value r0    Fvalue df1   df2   p.value conf.level lbound ubound
  <chr>   <chr>   <list<d> <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> 
1 1       1        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) 0.75  0     4      2     2     0.2     0.95       -8.74~ 0.993~
2 2       2        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) 0.75  0     4      2     2     0.2     0.95       -8.75  0.993~
3 3       1        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) 4.99~ 0     1      2     2     0.5     0.95       -38    0.974~
4 4       2        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) -8.3~ 0     0.999~ 2     2     0.5     0.95       -38    0.974~
5 5       2        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) 0.88~ 0     8.999~ 2     2     0.1     0.95       -3.33~ 0.997~
6 6       1        [3 x 2] 3        2      twow~ cons~ aver~ ICC(C,2) 1     0     Inf    2     2     0       0.95       1      1
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this! I thought that the psych function 'cohen.kappa' was only for nominal values? My raters have a scaling score from 1-4...wouldn't that be ordinal?

Comment: @NewBee If you need to use `icc()`, replace the mutate part with `mutate(result = map(.x = data, .f = function(x) enframe(unlist(icc(x)))))`. This returns results. The only thing is that you have all sorts of information. You may need to do subset, I think. Otherwise, replace the mutate part with `mutate(result = map(.x = data, .f = function(x) enframe(unlist(icc(x))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")))`. This returns a wide-format data. Try either and see which you prefer.

Comment: @NewBee I added a new version with `icc()`. Have a look.